# How can I modify a property of a variable in a logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I need to get counts of records matching a category and subcategory, then include the summary data in an email.

I was thinking to follow the flow:

```
create a variable (Counts: object, {}))
-> forEach category(
  forEach subcategory(
    Run Analytics Query
    -> Set Variable (Counts)))
-> Visualize Analytics Query # gets raw data to attach to email
-> Send Email # somehow iterating over same category and subcategory to inject summary data in the email
```

My question is, how do I set *just a property* of the Counts variable? or, failing that, what is a good way I can keep track of my results such that I can use the same nested for loop to build the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here provide a sample to just modify one property of variable(object) for your reference.

**1.** I initialize a variable named `Counts` shown as:

[image]

**2.** Then initialize another variable named `temp` shown as:

[image]

**3.** I want to change the value of `property2` in variable `Counts` from `20` to `19`. So do it like below:

[image]

**4.** After that, do not forget update the value of variable `temp`:

[image]

In your situation, **step 1** and **step 2** should be outside of the "**For each**" loop because "**For each**" loop doesn't allow "**Initialize variable**" action exist.

================================**Update**=================================

[image]
`concat('"property2":"', string(variables('Counts')?['property2']), '"')`

[image]
`json(replace(variables('temp'), variables('oneProperty'), '"property2":"19"'))`

Comment: this is interesting, but I am in a nested for loop, there are _a lot_ of variables that will have be carried over if I were to do it this way.. not sure this is practical

Comment: Hi @robertotomás For your requirement, we have more than one solutions to implement it. But all of them are not simple. You can also implement it by `replace()` method or create a function with modify property code in it and call the function in your logic app. I update my answer with the solution by `replace()` method for your reference.